# How to control the very audio play icon instead of looping them all?

Tags: javascript, foreach, dataset, toggle, html5-audio

Music and Icons are linking alright. I've been trying to toggle the icon for play and pause, and it work.
But how can I toggle only the one with music playing?

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="album-btn" data-music="Nutcracker">NutCracker
  <i class="fas fa-3x fa-play-circle"></i>
</div>
<div class="album-btn" data-music="Kinderszenen"> Kinderszenen
  <i class="fas fa-3x fa-play-circle"></i>
</div>

 <audio id="Kinderszenen" src="https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/ac35d32b11fdf0d60f676b0060fd1874d663726f?cid=774b29d4f13844c495f206cafdad9c86"></audio>
 <audio id="Nutcracker" src="https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/08f0833d7a2132f0a3863bb51b439a3061f55717?cid=774b29d4f13844c495f206cafdad9c86"></audio>
```

And JavaScript

```
const musicOn = document.querySelectorAll('.album-btn');  
const controlIcon = document.querySelectorAll('.album-btn .fas');  

musicOn.forEach(comeOn =>{
  comeOn.addEventListener('click', ()=> musicToggle(comeOn))
})

function musicToggle(comeOn) {

  const musicAudio = document.getElementById(comeOn.dataset.music);

  controlIcon.forEach(playPause => {

    if (playPause.classList.contains('fa-play-circle')){

        musicAudio.play(playPause);
        playPause.classList.remove('fa-play-circle');
        playPause.classList.add('fa-pause-circle');
    } else {
      musicAudio.pause(playPause);
      playPause.classList.remove('fa-pause-circle');
      playPause.classList.add('fa-play-circle');
    }
 })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the paused event to check audio is playing or not

```
let aud = document.getElementById("myAudio");
alert("Audio paused: ", aud.paused);
```

Also you can get the first played range, You can get the starting and ending seconds.

```
let aud = document.getElementById("myAudio");
alert("Start: " + aud.played.start(0) + " End: " + aud.played.end(0));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using e.target

```
const musicOn = document.querySelectorAll('.album-btn');

const controlMusic = document.querySelectorAll('.album-btn .fas');

musicOn.forEach(comeOn =>{
  comeOn.addEventListener('click', e=> musicToggle(comeOn, e))
})

function musicToggle(comeOn, e) {

  const musicAudio = document.getElementById(comeOn.dataset.music);
 
  let playPause = e.target
  
    if (playPause.classList.contains('fa-play-circle')){
     
      musicAudio.play(playPause);
      
      playPause.classList.remove('fa-play-circle');
      playPause.classList.add('fa-pause-circle');
      playPause.style.color = "#fff";
    } else {
      
      musicAudio.pause(playPause);

      playPause.classList.remove('fa-pause-circle');
      playPause.classList.add('fa-play-circle');
    }
}
```